# How to delete a subcollection from firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

so am new using firestore to store data. at the moment i need to delete data already saved in the Firestore through my App. I have tried

```
  Future<void> removeDocument(String id, String userId){
    return ref.document(userId).collection(userId).document(id).delete().whenComplete((){
      print("DELETE DONE::");
    });

  }
```

But its not working.
The thing is I used the userId to save the user details[image]

now I want to delete the data but it does not delete the data even though the print message shows in my Log.
The method below is how i add data to the Firestore

```
 Future<void> addDocument(Map data, String userId){
    return ref.document(userId).collection(userId).add(data);
  }


void setupLocatorWorkout() {
  locatorWorkout.registerLazySingleton(() => Api('workout_goal'));
  locatorWorkout.registerLazySingleton(() => CRUDRemoteDataSource());
}




 Api(this.path){
    print("$path");
    ref = _db.collection(path); // this is the base collection
  }
```

please what am i doing wrong here?
Thank you!!!

Comment: First comment, not an answer: it is a best practice to use hard-coded names for collections, since you can't get a list of collections with the client-side SDKs (such as the Flutter one you're using). So more idiomatic would be `ref.document(userId).collection("somethingThatDescribesTheThingsInThisCollection").document(id).`

Comment: Does the `DELETE DONE::` print? Are there any errors in the log output? How are you populating `id`? If you use a hardcoded value for that ID, does it work?

Comment: the "DELETE DONE::" shows in my Log, the id is from the firestore "PnEMmhb8bM8QB24dbUVi"

Answer (score 1):

**Delete a User by UID:**

```
  void deleteUser(User user) async {
    await db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
            .document(user.uid)
            .delete()
            .then((_) {
                print('User deleted.');
            });
  }
```

- Don't forget to add `import 'dart:async';` at the top

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you shouldn't.
According to the [Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections), you should not do this because:

> While it is possible to delete a collection from a mobile/web client, doing so has negative security and performance implications.

However the link shows how it can be done frome some platforms.

Comment: I realize I have answered the question of the title, but in the description, you seem to have a problem with deleting a document, which is an entirely different thing.